# Android - FCM onMessageReceived not called even with data payload when app is killed

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was wondering why my `onMessageReceived` is not called when my app is in background. While the FCM documentation says that if you only send "data" payload, `onMessageReceived` method will be triggered.

I was sending the http post request from my server using this payload

```
"to" : "x-FIr4x-0-x-j47s0KWZOZGOzBRYzcLdI4MBy6_MmCjZFOZuuuNJO4w5x5HCmw",
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "data" : {
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "title": "Collapsing A",
        "test" : "Data for key one",
    }
  })
```

If the app is in foreground, it works, but when I swiped it, it doesn't work. My phone is ASUS Zenfone Max

Comment: Add notification object like data

Comment: Could you check if the ASUS Zenfone Max has a whitelist of apps that can run in the background? If so then you may have to add your app to the whitelist for FCM to work in the background.